# Is there an option to limit the number to columns in a sink export into BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I created a sink export to load audit logs into BigQuery. However, there are a large number of columns that I don't need from the audit log. Is there a way to pick and choose the columns in the sink export?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot specify the columns in the sink to BigQuery. Your best option is to place a view over the top of the table(s) to restrict the columns you see.

Comment: Are you interested in reducing cost, or limiting the visibility of some of the data, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

We need to define our reason for wanting to reducing the number of columns.  My thinking is that you are concerned about costs.  If we look at active storage, we find that the current price is $0.02 / GB with the first 10GB free each month.  If the data is untouched for 90 days, that storage cost drops to $0.01/GB.  Next we have to estimate how much storage is used for recording all columns for a month vs recording just the storage you want to record.  If we can make some projections, then we can make a call on how much the cost might change *if* we reduced storage usage.  What we will want to estimate will be the number of log records to be exported per month and the size of the average log record if written as-is today vs a log record with only minimally needed fields.

If we do find that there is a distinction that makes a significant cost saving, one further thought would be to export the log entries to Pub/Sub and have them trigger a cloud function.  However, I'm dubious that we might end up finding that the savings on BQ storage is then lost due to the cost of Pub/Sub and Cloud Function (and possibly BQ streaming insert).

Another thought might be to realize that the BQ log records are written to tables named by "day".  We could have a batch job that runs after a days worth of records are written that copies only the columns of interest to a new table.  Again, we are going to have to watch that we don't end up with higher costs elsewhere in our attempt to reduce storage costs.

Comment: Doing some arithmetic, I seem to have arrived at about 18 cents/month for an average 1K log entry being moved to BQ at the rate of 1 new log entry/second (about 2.6GB/month)